# Vertically resize StackPanel to fit around its contents

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a textbox inside a `StackPanel` and the `TextBox` is set to `AcceptsReturn`, so when you press the Enter/Return key the textbox will become bigger in height.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make the surrounding `StackPanel` change in height along with the textbox. So when the textbox changes, so should the `StackPanel`.

How can we do this?

```
    <GridView x:Name="texties" Grid.Row="1" Margin="120, 0, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Something, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical" Width="210" >
                    <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 0" AcceptsReturn="True" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: Try removing the `Margin` property, and setting `Height=Auto` on the stackpanel

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I kind of need that Margin there, but I took it out anyway and set Height="Auto" and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: It is not the stackpanel that is the problem

Comment: So it's one of the Parent elements. DataTemplate/GridView.ItemTemplate/GridView... Not sure how I'm going to make those "fit-to-content". Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample you are not setting the `GridView.ItemsPanel`. The default value of `GridView.ItemsPanel` is `<WrapGrid />` which has a set cell size that cannot be changed. You might be tempted to update to `<VariableSizedWrapGrid />` but this control cannot change span values except during render. If what you want is even possible, it will require that you use `<StackPanel/>` as your `GridView.ItemsPanel`. However, `<StackPanel/>` does not wrap natively, so you will either need to locate a wrapping version someone else has made, make your own, or live with it in a single row or column.

Some developers attempt to change the size of their template based on the height of their `<TextBlock />`. This is a good idea but a difficult tech to execute. It turns out that the size of a UI Element is not determined until it is rendered and so you have to render it first, and then it is too late. If you want to see how one developer has accomplished this calculation (consider the difficulty of font-family and font-size and margin, etc) look [here](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/DynamicTextBlock/DynamicTextBlock.cs). Such a calc would allow you to use `<VariableSizedWrapGrid />`.

In this sample he is calculating for an ellipse, but it's ~the same calculation.

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    // just to make the code easier to read
    bool wrapping = this.TextWrapping == TextWrapping.Wrap;


    Size unboundSize = wrapping ? new Size(availableSize.Width, double.PositiveInfinity) : new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, availableSize.Height);
    string reducedText = this.Text;


    // set the text and measure it to see if it fits without alteration
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reducedText)) reducedText = string.Empty;
    this.textBlock.Text = reducedText;
    Size textSize = base.MeasureOverride(unboundSize);


    while (wrapping ? textSize.Height > availableSize.Height : textSize.Width > availableSize.Width)
    {
        int prevLength = reducedText.Length;

        if (reducedText.Length > 0)
            reducedText = this.ReduceText(reducedText);    

        if (reducedText.Length == prevLength)
            break;

        this.textBlock.Text = reducedText + "...";
        textSize = base.MeasureOverride(unboundSize);
    }

    return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
}
```

Best of luck.